# How to force/require TLS connections on SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

You can make a secure connection to a SQl Azure instance following [these instructions from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-tutorial#view-how-to-connect-an-application-to-your-database-using-a-secure-connection-string). However, this only works when the user specifies it in the connection string. How do I set SQL Azure to reject any insecure connections, should a user forget to set the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All connections to Azure SQL Azure are encrypted even when encryption is not specified. When a client first attempts a connection to SQL Azure, it sends an initial connection request. Consider this a "pre-pre-connection" request. At this point the client does not know if SSL/Encryption is required and waits an answer from SQL Azure to determine if SSL is indeed required throughout the session (not just the login sequence, the entire connection session). A bit is set on the response indicating so. Then the client library disconnects and reconnects armed with this information.

For example, when you set "Encrypt connection" setting on SQL Server Management Studio you avoid the "pre-pre-connection", you are preventing any proxy from turning off the encryption bit on the client side of the proxy, this way attacks like man-in-the-middle attack are avoided.

Answer (score 1):

"Regardless of the client library chosen, data is transferred using tabular data stream (TDS) over a secure sockets layer (SSL). Windows Azure SQL Database doesn’t support unencrypted connections. This will ensure data transmission is secure and can help prevent man-in-the-middle Jump attacks."

I don't know if this is true, I have it from "https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2763.windows-azure-sql-database-connection-encryption.aspx", but the connection was not secure (!!!!)

Comment: The TechNet Wiki article was reviewed and this is correct! From the official doc: `"All connections to Azure SQL Database require encryption (TLS/SSL) at all times while data is "in transit" to and from the database."`